# I'm not sure how to best organize data so that it can be serialized by the XML Serializer

Tags: c#, xml, object, serialization, dictionary

I have a Setting struct which contains a `name`, `description` and `type` as `strings`, as well as a `value` as  `Object`. Now there is a class which contains an array of settings. This class basically acts as a factory which creates objects which then should contains lists/arrays of these `settings` assinged to keys. My best idea to do this would be to create a Dictionary like this: `Dictionary<KeyCode, Setting[]>` or even better `Dictionary<KeyCode, Dictionary<string, Settings>>` (organized by setting names), but unfortunately Dictionaries can't be serialized via XML. Now I have two questions about this:

Can XML serialize and deserialize objects of type `Object` (They only contain value types like float and bool)?

How to assign the setting lists to keys while maintaining serializability with xml ?

Comment: `struct` seems a bad choice for this type.

Comment: Maybe don't use XmlSerializer, but rather serialize it yourself, perhaps through LINQ to XML?

Comment: I just made a quick test with a DataContractSerializer and was able to serialize a dictionary<string,person> without anything special (person being just two strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an IXmlSerializable Dictionary. This is taken from [Paul Welter's Weblog - XML Serializable Generic Dictionary](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("dictionary")]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable
{
    #region IXmlSerializable Members
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        bool wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        reader.Read();

        if (wasEmpty)
            return;

        while (reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement("item");

            reader.ReadStartElement("key");
            TKey key = (TKey)keySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            reader.ReadStartElement("value");
            TValue value = (TValue)valueSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            this.Add(key, value);

            reader.ReadEndElement();
            reader.MoveToContent();
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        foreach (TKey key in this.Keys)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("item");

            writer.WriteStartElement("key");
            keySerializer.Serialize(writer, key);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("value");
            TValue value = this[key];
            valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

To your second question, you can tell an Object type property the possible values it make accept by using the XmlElement tag:

```
public class MyClass
{
   [XmlElement("a", Type = typeof(int))]
   [XmlElement("b", Type = typeof(string))]
   [XmlElement("c", Type = typeof(float))]
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

The xml would generate each value depending on the type:

```
<MyClass>
  <b>abc</b>
</MyClass>

<MyClass>
  <a>123</a>
</MyClass>

<MyClass>
  <c>45.7</c>
</MyClass>
```

Comment: Thanks, what exactly do a,b,and c mean ?

Comment: They are the name the tag will receive.

Comment: hmm, so if the value is an int, the tag will be <a>1</a> ?